# how can we use or_where_in along with other where condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, where-clause, codeigniter-3, where-in

Here am stuck with the `or_where_in` condition.while using this condition the result is obtaining correctly here is my code please have a look

```
public function get_date_wise_sales_info($start_date, $end_date,$type=NULL,$user_id=NULL,$get_all_user_ids=NULL)
{
    if(!empty($type))
    {
        $this->db->where('type',$type);
    }
    if(!empty($user_id))
    {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }
    if(!empty($get_all_user_ids))
    {
        $this->db->or_where_in('user_id',$get_all_user_ids);
    }

    $this->db->where("DATE(bills.created_at) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'");

    $this->db->order_by('bills.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('bills');
    return $query->result();
}
```

here by using `or_where_in` condition the results of not selected `dates` are coming and if i remove `or_where_in` the result is obtaining correctly.how to write the correct syntax of using `or_where_in`.i wrote `where_in` instead of `or_where_in` but nothing is getting displayed and am using codeigniter 3.1.5 version

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: What are you trying to do with $get_all_user_ids? What is the difference with $user_id?

Comment: `$get_all_user_ids` is the child id that comes under `$user_id`

Comment: So can `$user_id` be empty when `$get_all_user_ids` is not?

Comment: yes it can be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you are trying to do, but because of the OR statement you may need to use [query grouping](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping).

```
public function get_date_wise_sales_info($start_date, $end_date,$type=NULL,$user_id=NULL,$get_all_user_ids=NULL)
{
    if(!empty($type))
    {
        $this->db->where('type',$type);
    }

    if(!empty($user_id) && !empty($get_all_user_ids))
    {
        // Check for both, with OR
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->or_where_in('user_id',$get_all_user_ids);
        $this->db->group_end();
    } 
    else if(!empty($user_id))
    {
        // Only check for $user_id
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }
    else if(!empty($get_all_user_ids))
    {
        // Only check for $get_all_user_ids
        $this->db->where_in('user_id', $get_all_user_ids);
    }

    $this->db->where("DATE(bills.created_at) BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'");

    $this->db->order_by('bills.id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('bills');
    return $query->result();
}
```

EDIT: this is a bit more complex than simply adding grouping. Updated to check for all possibilities.